# Questions about code signing Mac App with Developer ID

Tags: macos, code-signing

I have several questions about signing Mac App with Developer ID:

First of all, I'm working on a project utilizing GateKeeper. So I have to(?) sign my App with Developer ID.

1. Do I need a provisioning profile to sign with Developer ID?
   In the build settings tab, the Developer ID certification is marked as `Identities without Provisioning Profiles`. Looking around in Mac Provision Portal, I found no place to generate provisioning profile to match Developer ID cert rather than submission certs.
   So do I need a provisioning profile to sign with Developer ID?
2. After archiving my app, when I chose Export Developer ID-signed Application in the organizer, my Developer ID certification is marked with a yellow warning icon. But I can still chose the cert and sign it. Is it OK?
3. After signing my app, I used `sudo spctl -a -v MyApp.app` to test my app with `sudo spctl --master-enable` runed before that. The result is as followed:

   ```
   EIM.app: rejected
   source=Developer ID
   ```

Is this rejection related to the warning in question 2?

It's my first time distributing Mac App with Developer ID, thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you ever solve that issue? I am currently also getting that yellow warning sign when trying to distribute a Developer ID signed build via Xcode's organizer.

Comment: @weichsel I haven't solved it yet. I'm using "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re: Provisioning profiles and DeveloperID— they are unnecessary.   You should be able to accept your DeveloperID in the *automatic* section of the **Code Signing Identity** portion of the **Build Settings**.   If you cannot, your key may be missing or there may be something else wrong with the database that contains the information.

First, go into Keychain Access and verify that your DeveloperID certificate has an accompanying private key associated with it (this will be visible under a disclosure triangle).  If it does not, then you should go check around to see if you saved off the key related to that certificate anywhere, because if you can't find and reimport it (from, for example, a Developer Profile exported from Xcode), you will need to revoke and reissue the certificate, since there's no way to sign it.

Second, there is a known bug in 4.6.1 that can corrupt a cached database containing information from the developer portal.   There's no specific indication that this behavior can be caused by this problem, but before following the next step, you might want to give it a try.   Basically, you will need to quit Xcode, move aside (or delete) `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/connect1.apple.com 4.6.1.db` (yes, there's a space in that file name), restart Xcode, go to the **Organizer** and **Refresh** your profiles and certificates.

If this doesn't work, you may want to consider revoking your Developer ID.

**WARNING** If you have successfully distributed code with the certificate, do not revoke it until you have visited Apple's web site (https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/certificates/) and thoroughly understand the implications to shipped code for revoking a developer id. Specifically that installed software will continue to work, but users will not be able to install/reinstall binaries signed with the original certificate.

If you have never successfully distributed code with the certificate (or if your key is irrecoverably lost), you may want to go to the portal and revoke and then reissue your Developer ID certificate. Once you have revoked it, you can create a new certificate by requesting a new certificate.

Comment: I've checked in Keychain, and the "Developer ID Application" cert do have a private key associated. In the "Build Settings" section, "Developer ID Application" is automatically matched and selected. I can archive the app successfully. But when exporting as Developer ID-signed Application, there is a yellow warning mark beside the "Developer ID Application" cert. Although I can still chose this cert to sign the app, the exported app can not pass the spctl check with `--master-enable`ed. Is provisioning profile needed to sign app with Developer ID Application cert?

Comment: No, you don't need a provisioning profile for the Developer ID app cert (as indicated in my first paragraph).   If you use the third option in Export and just export the App instead of re-signing it (second option), do you have any better luck?   The yellow triangle still makes me concerned that you have a certificate store problem.   You may need to try the certificate revocation if you haven't distributed before, or at least manually deleting the certificate from your Keychain (take care not to delete the Private Key) and re-download the certificate.